# what does "let $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);" do? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

please can someone explain what this line of code does. Thank you.

```
let $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Google](//www.google.com/search?q=js+document.getElementById.bind%28document%29%3B) or reading the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: Please be more specific what part you don't understand. Is it the `let`? The `$`? The `=`? The `document.getElementById`? The `.bind(document)`?